# Reset Git Branch to last commit? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build out a feature on an app, so I started a branch. I'm a couple hours into building my feature and now I realize that I have a mess. I generated a model and a bunch of changes, all I want now is to go back to my last commit and start over with a different approach. How can I delete all my changes and simply go back to the git repo head and start over schema and all?

Comment: If I do that I still have schema changes sticking around

Comment: Did you migrate your database? If so, first rollback all relevant migrations, _then_ git reset hard.

Comment: The nominated duplicate covers the git part of this question, but does not cover anything additional that should be done for Rails (see @SergioTulentsev's comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**reset hard** - Make sure you are permanently deleting all the changes:

```
git log  #get your last commit id
git reset --hard commit_id
```

Comment: Still have my schema change in there

Comment: @CameronBass you need to rollback the migrations you have made. `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=<version>`